# Angular - Needing to save Module/Component files to compile when modifying the template

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 10 (which is all I've ever used). I don't know if what I'm seeing is a common problem or whether the problem lies in something I'm doing wrong.

When serve my project using ng-serve, quite frequently, if editing a template, I'll get a compiler error, warning me of an error in the Component or the Module. If I then go to the culprit Component/Module and save the file, the project compiles without any issues.

It does seem to occur if the project autosaves when there is an error in the template. Sometimes simply saving the template again allows it to recompile, but often I get the above issue, needing to either re-save the Module or Component, despite not making any direct changes to them.

Is this a common error and should I get used to it? Or is something going wrong in my environment?

I have a similar but somewhat rarer issue, where components will fail to load properly (or without styling), and I need to go into each Component/Template and save them again to allow them to display.

Comment: what IDE (editor) are you using?

Comment: The latest version of VS Code

Comment: Do you have auto-save enabled in the file menu?

Comment: Yes. I have disabled that now though. Is saving while there are errors a reason for this happening? Surely saving the file again once the errors are corrected should be enough to allow Angular to compile, without having to resave the Module/Component.

Comment: If a save causes an erorr (which auto save is most likely to cause), angular has some issues recovering from this once you start editing other files. Too many of these errors, and angular gets out of sync with it changes. I guess that's what happening. Try coding without autosave, and see if you still have these issues